# NoMethodError: undefined method `url_whitelist=' for DatabaseCleaner:Module

Tags: ruby, database-cleaner

In the [safeguard document section](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#safeguards), it says we could specify whitelist url:

> In Ruby, a URL whitelist can be specified. When specified, DatabaseCleaner will only allow DATABASE_URL to be equal to one of the values specified in the url whitelist like so:

But I am getting a `NoMethodError`:

```
require "database_cleaner"
DatabaseCleaner.url_whitelist = %w(mysql2://root@mysql)
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
```

This `url_whitelist` is defined [here](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/blob/e13522d856d6e0fc0952e235ab58dde7002d82ca/lib/database_cleaner.rb#L33), introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/pull/526).

Using DatabaseCleaner 1.7.0.

Comment: 1.7.0 was released on 19 Apr and the `url_whitelist` addition was [commited](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/commit/c0013de1ee7afb4e25a0581940e22408f73273f9) a day after on 20 Apr (merged 25 May). Seems like you have to either use the master branch or wait for the next release.

Comment: Are you on an old Rails version? 5.1+ shouldn't need DatabaseCleaner in transaction mode. :/ ()

Comment: You're right! @Stefan

Comment: @matthewd Thank you for the tip and ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current latest version 1.7.0 does not include this method ‍♀️

Use master branch instead for now as of 2018 August 9th.

You can check if a newer version has been released at [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner/versions).

Comment: SO doesn't seem to get the "Woman facepalming" emoji quite right ;-)